# Ruby on rails Error : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

I am trying to control my Chrome browser through the rails console using `watir`:

```
pry(main)> browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
```

and when I try to

```
pry(main)> browser.goto("google.com")
```

I get:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515
from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
```

Anybody know how to fix this? I have no idea where it is coming from. Thank you

Comment: have you installed the latest version of chromedriver?

Comment: I think so, its the one from this page http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/

Comment: there are a *lot* of variations on this problem scattered across the internet. chromedriver is a bit finicky, so if you're not bound to chrome, you could "fix" your problem by using firefox instead. that being said, i'll do my best to help you with your problem. could you open a terminal and run the chromedriver exe manually and tell me the output?

Comment: yes     C:\Users\meta>chromedriver.exe
          Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 9515

Comment: and then it does not do anything

Comment: hm.. could you try adding `gem "chromedriver-helper"` to your Gemfile and running `bundle install`?

Comment: yes just did, unfortunately i stil get the same error.

Comment: okay, next try downloading chromedriver 2.30 [from here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.30/) and replacing your old chromedriver. your current version seems to be a few versions behind.

Comment: YES ! It works perfectly now, thank you very much for your help. I am new to this website, is there anyway i can recommend you in some way?

Comment: glad to help! i'll write up my comment in an answer form, which you can accept to let the world know that answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of potential reasons for this error to pop up, but it is generally related to version incompatibilities. From the comments it looks like you're running an outdated version of chromedriver. If you follow [this link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.30/) you can download chromedriver 2.30, the latest version, which will likely fix your problem.